# How to "hide" a text from Batch-File?

Tags: batch-file, text, plugins, cursor-position

I want to know if there any solution to this:

Main.bat:

```
@echo off
goto 'input'

: 'input'
cls
set "inp="
set /p inp=What would you like to do?
set firstresponse=%inp:~0,5%
if %firstresponse%==help goto 'help'
pause
if /I %firstresponse%==check set firstresponse=dir && set                             
executeparttwo=%inp:~5%
if /I %firstresponse%==remov goto 'remove'

%firstresponse%%executeparttwo%
pause
goto 'input'

: 'remove'
set "firstresponse=" && set firstresponse=%inp:~0,6%
if /I %firstresponse%==remove set firstresponse=del
set executeparttwo=%inp:~6%
%firstresponse%%executeparttwo%
pause
goto 'input'

: 'help'
cls
echo Check = Dir in regular command prompt, checks a directory.
echo Remove = del in regular command prompt, deletes something.
pause
goto 'input'
```

if the User typed an invalid command, it will show like what CMD does ( 'command' is not recongnized...)

What i want to do is to replace the CMD invalid command text to my own one like "command" is an invalid command, but to do that i need to "hide" the CMD one (because if the user typed a invalid command it will not show him a "custom message")

I tried to use some Batch plugins like batbox, CursorPos etc... To replace the cursor position but i didn't get what i wanted. So if anyone have a solution i will be very appreciated!

- Have a nice day, and thanks for reading!

Comment: you can check if the command exists with this - https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-which.html . Also errorlevel is set to 9009 when the command is non existent.

Comment: Use the `choice` command or another method which limits the end user to only valid entries!

Comment: Thanks for the answers, as you can see in my post the %firstresponse%%executeparttwo% means what the user typed will get executed as a command and if the command was invalid it will print the 'command' is not recongnized... And what i want to do is to "hide" that message and replace it by my own one.

-Have a nice day!

Comment: As you can see in my comment, if you code your script to only accept valid entries/commands, then you don't need to hide 'not recognized' messages, because there won't be any!

Comment: @Compo I tried the `choice` command but it won't let you type a long command such as `del` with it syntax or a custom commands `apt-get update` etc... It only accept one single lettre, Thanks for the answer!
-Have a nice day!

Comment: With `choice` the commands are preset, your end user selects the item digit/letter relevant to the command. Regardless of that command you can still preset your list of valid commands and if your end user doesn't select one from the list, it doesn't proceed. It's all a matter of structuring/designing the project before throwing a load of inappropriate commands on the page, getting it wrong, and expecting someone else to help you put sticking plasters over it later!

Comment: written like that your code will be able to execute command with 5 or less letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your splitting the command and parameters is not ideal, there is a much easier and safer way. Also, the method of an own subroutine for each command is suboptimal (especially, when you add more and more commands).

```
@echo off
call :commandlist  REM build translation table

:input
REM get input line:
set /p "commandline=Enter Command: "
REM split to command and parameters
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%commandline%") do (
  set "command=_%%a"
  set "params=%%b"
)
REM check for valid command:
set _|findstr /bi "%command%=" >nul || (
  echo invalid command: '%command:~1%'.
  goto :input
)
REM execute the command:
call %%%command%%% %params%
goto :input

:Commandlist
set "_check=dir /b"
set "_remove=del"
set "_help=:help"
set "_where=call echo %%cd%%"
set "_change=cd"
set "_apt-get=:apt"
set "_bye=exit /b"   'secret' exit command  ;)
goto :eof

:help
echo Check = Dir in regular command prompt, checks a directory.
echo Remove = del in regular command prompt, deletes something.
echo Where = echo %%cd%% in regular command prompt, print working folder.
echo Change = cd in regular command prompt, change working folder
goto :eof

:apt 
if /i "%~1" == "update" echo updating... & goto :eof
if /i "%~1" == "whatever" echo whatevering... & goto :eof
echo invalid command: '%command:~1% %1'
goto :eof
```

(Note to experienced batch users: yes I know there is a possibility for some "code injection")

Comment: Great! It worked! but when i make my own custom commands like "apt-get update" or any other command with "space" in it, it will not work. If there is any solution i will be very appreciated!
-Have a nice day, and Thanks!

Comment: I guess there is a reason that in every language I know, a command is just a single word (plus switches and/or parameters). (even Commands like `wmic` or `netsh` that look like two (or more) word commands, are really one-word commands that do parse the second (...) "command part" themselves. So treat it as a one-word command with a parameter - see my edited answer

Comment: Your code really helped me thanks again, and the last line of your reply got me wondering, so can you please tell me how can you "inject" a code through the input?